# <Closed> Unable to Identify the Mobile Elements Using Page Factory AndroidFindBy annotation

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, ui-automation

> Hi All,
> I am Practicing Mobile Application Automation using TestNG and Page Object Factory. Unfortunately script is not able to find the Mobile Element. Please find the below Code Snippet and Let me know your Inputs to resolve the issue.

> **dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> **Test Class:**

```
   public class LoginTest extends Demo
{
    
    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver =null;
    @BeforeMethod
    public static void androidSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        
         DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        
        String appPath = "/Users/hnum/Desktop/MobileAutomation/MobileAutomation/Resources/MG.apk";
        File app = new File(appPath);
        
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "emulator-5554");
        caps.setCapability("appWaitDuration",20000);
        caps.setCapability("appWaitForLaunch",false);
        caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
        
        
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        
    
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Execution started");
    }
    
    
    @Test
    public static void Login() throws InterruptedException {
        
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("Test Execution started");
        SelectEnvironment_Page selectEnvironment_Page = new SelectEnvironment_Page(driver);
        selectEnvironment_Page.dropDown_Select_Environment_click();
    }
    

}
```

> **Page Class:**

```
**Page Class:**

public class SelectEnvironment_Page 
{
    static public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    
    
    public SelectEnvironment_Page(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)), SelectEnvironment_Page.class);
        
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "EnvironmentPopUpSelectEnvironmentLabel")
    MobileElement txt_Select_Environment;
        
    @AndroidFindBy (xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='Change Environment']")
    MobileElement dropDown_Select_Environment;
    
    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='QA']")
    MobileElement QAEnvironment;
    
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "EnvironmentPopUpChangeEnvironmentButton")
    MobileElement btnChangeEnvironment;
    

    
    public void txt_Select_Environment_Visible(){
        txt_Select_Environment.isDisplayed();
    }

    public void dropDown_Select_Environment_click(){
        dropDown_Select_Environment.click();
    }

    public void QAEnvironment_click() {
        QAEnvironment.click();
    }
    
    public void btnChangeEnvironment_click() {
        btnChangeEnvironment.click();
    }
    
}
```

> **Getting Below Error:**

Execution started

Test Execution started

FAILED: Login

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.click()" because "this.dropDown_Select_Environment" is null
at Pages.SelectEnvironment_Page.dropDown_Select_Environment_click(SelectEnvironment_Page.java:55)
at TestCases.LoginTest.Login(LoginTest.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 0):

> issue got resolved, hence long this question.

Resolution: It was Java, Appium Java Client version was mismatched.
now i am able to find the element using pom approach.
Currently it worked for below dependency version:

Java Version: 11.0.15.1

Java-Client: 7.6.0

Selenium-Java: 3.141.59

TestNG: 7.4.0